# Копирование файлов в bash c сохранением структуры и одновременным переименованием

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

Есть на линуксовом серверочке некоторый каталог /upload в котором валяется несколько гигабайт картинок, распиханные по двух или трёхуровневой структуре папок, например:

- upload/slides/presentation2015/Ueberblick_Messehalle_beim_Mobile_World_Congress.png
- upload/x7v/b7f/b7f8abcf54d20d7a482e56405b3b51ec.jpg

И нужно некоторые из них перенести в /home/user/newsite/data/news/oldimg/ с сохранением структуры папок.

> Пример.
>
> Был файл:
>
> /var/www/html/upload/x7v/b7f/b7f8abcf54d20d7a482e56405b3b51ec.jpg
>
> Копию положили в:
>
> /home/user/newsite/data/news/oldimg/x7v/b7f/b7f8abcf54d20d7a482e56405b3b51ec.jpg

Это можно сделать командой cp с ключом `--parent`, я попробовал -- результат тот, который нужен.

Один из тестовых прогонов написанного скрипта показал наличие проблемы на реальных файлах: часть имён файлов содержит [пробелы, амперсанды и прочие спецсимволы](https://www.tecmint.com/manage-linux-filenames-with-special-characters/) в количестве, которое исключает желание править руками.

И хотя я могу сформировать практически любой скрипт, у меня выбор: с ключом --parent нельзя одновременно указывать иное имя, либо прописывая полностью что куда копировать -- получаю ошибку, потому что структура каталогов ещё не создана.

Ну как-то так в сгенерированном скрипте это выглядело:

```
#cp --parent /var/www/html/upload/x7v/b7f/b7f8abcf54d20d7a482e56405b3b51ec.jpg  /home/user/newsite/data/news/oldimg/
cp /var/www/html/upload/x7v/b7f/b7f8abcf54d20d7a482e56405b3b51ec.jpg  /home/user/newsite/data/news/oldimg/x7v/b7f/b7f8abcf54d20d7a482e56405b3b51ec.jpg
```

И естественно, в /home/user/newsite/data/news/oldimg/ ещё нет папок x7v/b7f - некуда заливать.

Есть ли какой-то вариант указать cp хитрые ключики (может я что просмотрел в man'е?), чтобы можно было одним махом и каталоги создать и скопировать и переименовать по пути? Или может быть можно другие команды использовать, скажем я посматривал в сторону rsync с 127.0.0.1

Я понимаю, что я могу сгенерировать скрипт так, как мне надо, мне просто не нравится писать две строчки на одно действие, хочется большей лаконичности. (И в конце концов всегда можно вообще свернуть в плоскую структуру новых папок, переименовывая файлы в что-то гуидообразное.

Comment: а почему не получить список директорий сначала, создать их, а потом уже просто копировать файлы?

Comment: *нельзя одновременно указывать иное имя* — `$ install -D src dst`

Comment: -R не пробовали? -R, -r, --recursive copy directories recursively

Comment: Ну так *rsync* же. Он умеет безо всяких сетей локально синхронизировать. Да, а расширенные атрибуты сохранять требуется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариан с **tar**

```
 ~$ tar -cf path.tar path && tar -xf path.tar -C target_path
 ~$ tar -C source_path -cpf - . | tar -C target_path -xvf -

 -c Create  a  new  archive.  
 -p extract information about file permissions
 -C Change  to DIR before performing any operations.
```

Вариант с **cp**

```
~$ cp -R path target_path
~$ cp -rp

# можно просто создать жестку ссылку на дирректорию
~$ cp -Rl path target_path

-R, -r, --recursive copy directories recursively
-p same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```

Длинный вариант с **find**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

search_path="/var/www/html/upload"
target_path="/home/user/newsite/data/news/oldimg"
home_path="$HOME"

> dir_struct1
> dir_struct2

# Создаем структуру путей
find "$search_path" -type d -print0 \
 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' d; do
    target_full_path="${target_path}${d#$(echo "$search_path")}"
    mkdir -p "$target_full_path" 

    # И копируем файлы в найденой дирректории
    find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 \
     | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
        cp "${f}" "$target_full_path"
    done
done
# Проверка
cd "$search_path"
find ./ > "${home_path}/dir_struct2"

cd "$target_path"
find ./ > "${home_path}/dir_struct1"

cd "$home_path"
diff dir_struct2 dir_struct1
# End of script
```

Comment: Что-то у меня руки не дошли на прошлой неделе, подведу итоги. Мне очень понравился вариант баракина с install (не знал про такую команду), остальные комментарии тоже были полезными, но в итоге мне больше всего понравился однострочный вариант с `cp -R` (таки надо было всё же попробовать). С учётом того, что никто кроме вас не захотел дооформить -- вам достаётся не только upwote, но и галка. А вообще -- всем спасибо, накидали полезных идей.