# Синтаксис команды для копирования файла в другой каталог под другим именем

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, администрирование

Стоит задача, допустим, в каталоге var1 есть файл var1.txt его нужно скопировать в каталог var2 под именем var1_1.txt, то есть при копировании сразу должно поменяться имя файла. Вообще возможно ли это? И как тогда правильно задать синтаксис?
Или же только это делать просто копированием содержимого командой 
Подчеркиваю, мы не копируем дерево каталогов как в соседней теме, а просто копируем один единственный текстовый файл который сразу же необходимо переименовать. Тот вариант который я якобы дублирую нам не совсем подходит.

```
cat var1.txt > /home/var2/var1_1.txt
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Копирование файлов в bash c сохранением структуры и одновременным переименованием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723851/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-bash-c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Почитайте вопрос, который я привёл -- там сразу несколько разных способов решения.

Comment: @AK, что-то не очень улавливаю связь - в том вопросе речь про копирование дерева каталогов с содержимым, здесь же нужно просто скопировать файл в другое место под другим именем. Возможно, хватит простого использования `cp`.

Comment: @Vladimir В том вопросе файлы копировались по одному, потому что генерировался скрипт. Ваш вариант с basename в общем-то тоже сработает... если каталоги уже есть. А если нужно будет на лету создавать подпапки -- то удобнее посмотреть другие способы.

Comment: @AK Спасибо конечно за направление на тему, ну там немного не то что требуется, тут всего лишь требовалось скопировать один файл и при этом просто изменить имя, и как сказал @Vladimir тут вполне мне хватило для этой задачи одного простого `cp` ну почему я пошел более длинные путем сам не могу понять свою логику

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может, как-то так?

```
cp var1.txt ../var2/var1_1.txt
```

или для обработки большого числа файлов так:

```
cp var1.txt ../var2/`basename var1.txt .txt`_1.txt
```

Естественно, это просто пример для команды basename. В скрипте можно использовать переменные вместо реального имени var1.txt и расширения .txt.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую, я пошел более длинным путем и решил сделать так сначала скопировать файл `cp /var1/var1.txt var2` , а затем переименовать его командой `mv var1.txt var1_1.txt`, сейчас попробую Ваш вариант.

Comment: если это вопрос не для автоматизации обработки большого числа файлов, то почему не изменить имя сразу при копировании? `cp var1.txt ../var2/var1_1.txt`

Comment: блиин, это же гениально просто было... спасибо большое, как я не допер до этого изначально...

Comment: Useless use of shell fork followed by basename. Короче говоря, используйте специальные модификаторы переменных: %, %%, #, ##.

Comment: @0andriy, судя по обилию %% это комментарий от закоренелого виндузятника, которому всё нужно подробно разжевывать. Мой подход - всего лишь направить в нужную сторону, чтобы был интерес почитать man и потом самому решить что делать. И если бы автор вопроса попросил уточнить, тогда бы я привел пример со скриптом и переменными.

Comment: В этом и отличие ruSO от нормального. За "виндузятника" отдельное спасибо! А то подзабыл уже как там и что.